# Docker-maven-plugin PostgreSQL - create new database and apply Flyway migrations

Tags: maven-3, flyway, docker-maven-plugin

I want to use docker-maven-plugin to deploy PostgreSQL container and run some integration tests over it.

```
<plugin>
     <groupId>io.fabric8</groupId>
     <artifactId>docker-maven-plugin</artifactId>
     <version>0.20.0</version>
     <executions>
           <execution>
                <id>prepare-it-database</id>
                <phase>pre-integration-test</phase>
                <goals>
                     <goal>start</goal>
                </goals>
                <configuration>
                     <images>
                          <image>
                                <name>postgres:9.5.4</name>
                                <alias>it-database</alias>
                                <run>
                                    <ports>
                                        <port>it-database.port:5432</port>
                                    </ports>
                                    <wait>
                                        <log>database system is ready to accept connections</log>
                                            <time>20000</time>
                                    </wait>
                                </run>
                          </image>
                     </images>
                </configuration>
           </execution>
      </executions>
</plugin>
```

Is it possible to run another goal (mvn e.g. `flyway:migrate`) from this plugin?

Answer (score 0):

No, this plugin does not execute other Maven plugins (and very few do that).

What you need to do is to bind `d-m-p`'s `start` goal to `pre-integration-test`, and then also bind `flyway` plugin to `pre-integration-test` Maven phase.